# Task for matching floating point numbers

Tags: regex, pcre

Task:

```
MATCH:
3.45
5,4
.45
3e4
,54
4
4.
4,

DON'T MATCH:
4,5e
2e
.3.
2e,4
,4.
d34
2.45t
2,45.
```

Currently i came up with the following:

```
(?<=\s|^)[-+]?(?:(?:[.,]?\d+[.,]?\d*[eE]\d+(?!\w|[.,]))|[.,]?\d+[.,]?\d*(?!\w|[.,]))\b
```

That works for almost everything, except 2 last numbers (4. and 4,) and got stucked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use

```
(?<!\S)[-+]?[0-9]*(?:[.,]?[0-9]+(?:[eE][-+]?[0-9]+)?|(?<=\d)[,.])(?!\S)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/LEC1Te/2)

**Details**

- `(?<!\S)` - start of string or a whitespace must appear immediately to the left
- `[-+]?` - an optional `+` or `-`
- `[0-9]*` - 0+ digits
- `(?:[.,]?[0-9]+(?:[eE][-+]?[0-9]+)?|[,.])` - either

  - `[.,]?[0-9]+(?:[eE][-+]?[0-9]+)?` - an optional `.` or `,`, then 1+ digits, then an optional sequence of `e` or `E`, followed with an optional `.` or `,` and 1+ digits
  - `|` - or
  - `(?<=\d)[,.]` - a dot or comma only if preceded with a digit (to avoid matching standalone `.` or `,`)
- `(?!\S)` - end of string or a whitespace must appear immediately to the right.

Regex graph:

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You could use an [alternation](https://www.regular-expressions.info/alternation.html) to match 1+ digits followed by a dot or comma and 0+ digits or match the `Ee` part followed by 1+ digits.

Or match starting with a dot or comma followed by 1+ digits.

If this is the only thing to match on the line, you could use anchors `^` and `$` or use lookarounds to assert that there are no non whitespace chars on the left and right.

```
(?<!\S)(?:\d+(?:[.,]\d*|[eE]\d+)?|[.,]\d+)(?!\S)
```

**Pattern parts**

- `(?<!\S)` Assert what is directly to the left is non a non whitespace char
- `(?:` Non capturing group

  - `\d+` Match 1+ digits
  - `(?:` Non capturing group

    - `[.,]\d*` Match either `.` or `,` and 0+ digits
    - `|` Or
    - `[eE]\d+` Match `e` or `E` and 1+ digits
  - `)?` Close group and make it optional
  - `|` Or
  - `[.,]\d+` Match `.` or `,` and 1+ digits
- `)` Close group
- `(?!\S)` Assert what is directly to the right is non a non whitespace char

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/TyHGRB/1)